# My addEventListener isn't linking to my function... any help appreciated

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener

Making a hangman game. My addEventListener isn't communicating with my function. The wrong answer counter still goes up so there is a little life in there...

I had an input box and button and it worked. But to improve the look, I added a button for each letter and I've tried onClick, addeventListener but cannot get it to function.

```
function createLetterKeys(id, text, value) {
    var letterKey = document.createElement("div");
    letterKey.setAttribute("id", id);
    letterKey.innerHTML = text;
    letterKey.setAttribute("class", "keys");
    letterKey.addEventListener("click", playGame);
    lettersDiv.appendChild(letterKey);
}

createLetterKeys("a", "a", "a");

function playGame() {
    var guess = document.querySelectorAll("keys").value;
    var wrong = true;
    if (guessList.includes(guess)) {
        alert("You've already used that letter. Try again...");
    }
    if (guess == letter1) {
        document.getElementById("let1").innerHTML = guess;
        guessedRight.push(letter1);
        counter--;
        wrong = false;
        guessList.push(guess);
    }
    if (guess == letter1) {
        document.getElementById("let1").innerHTML = guess;
        guessedRight.push(letter1);
        counter--;
        wrong = false;
        guessList.push(guess);
    }
```

Above is a sample of the code (repeated in my code). The GUESS variable doesn't seem to being getting any info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.querySelectorAll returns a NodeList containing all the elements that match your selector. But these are actually all your letters - not only the clicked (guessed) letter. Moreover, NodeList has no "value" property. That's why you don't get anything in the "guess" variable.

If I am right, you actually want the clicked letter element instead. Use this.id in playGame() function to get the id of the clicked element. As your element's id is the letter, you can get the guessed letter easily:

```
var guess = this.id;
```

Later edit: I have added a working JSFiddle for this at https://jsfiddle.net/o57nd0L1/3/

Comment: Thank you so much. It works brilliantly. Such a simple solution that I couldn't for the life of me find on my own! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just forgot to add a *dot* to your `.keys` (use dots to select elements by class name).

`var guess = document.querySelectorAll(".keys").value;`